# Django get objects for many IDs

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a set of ID's that I'd like to retrieve all of the objects for. My current solution works, however it hammers the database with a a bunch of `get` queries inside a loop.

```
objects = [SomeModel.objects.get(id=id_) for id_ in id_set]
```

Is there a more efficient way of going about this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's an __in ([documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)) field lookup that you can use to get all objects for which a certain field matches one of a list of values

```
objects = SomeModel.objects.filter(id__in=id_set)
```

Works just the same for lots of different field types (e.g. CharFields), not just id fields.

Comment: If you can't give any other information other then just to pop the code in, at least format it. Since nobody can edit it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'll accept this answer in a few minutes.